# Using Near Feature Tool with Conditions

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, arcgis-10.1, proximity, conditional

I am using near feature tool in ArcGIS 10.1. However, I need to add another condition to it (not only the nearest). The feature (point) that i am looking for, is the nearest (point) and also doesnot cross another feature (line or area feature). For example, if the shortest distance line crosses another feature (line or area feature), then it has to start looking for another near feature (point) to which the shortest distance doesnot cross the feature (line or area). Is it possible using python?

Comment: have you tried using select by location before running the near tool?

Comment: Select by feature will not fulfil my objective. As I said above, near tool measures distance from a point to any feature and returns the objectid of it. I want the object id returned only if the nearest distance line doesnot touch a feature.

Comment: I understood your question, I was suggesting a first step where you eliminate, all line features that touch a feature before calculating the Nearest distance. ( This of course depends on whether, what you referred as 'feature' is a third dataset or the point features themselves from which you are going to calculate nearest distance)